# Understanding the Firebase and purpose of google cloud functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Let's say I'm developing app like Instagram: for iOS, Android and Web. I decided to use Google Firebase as it really seems to simplify the work.

The features user needs in the app are:

- Authorization/Registration
- Uploading photos
- Searching for other people, following them and see their photos

I come from traditional "own-backend" development where I do need to setup a server, create database and finally write the API to let the frontend retrieve the data from the server. That's the reason why it's unclear to me how it all works in Firebase.

So the question is how can I create such app:

1. Should I create my own API with cloud functions? Or it's ok to work with the database directly from the client-side?
2. If I work with the database directly why do I need cloud functions? Should I use them?

Sorry for such silly questions, but it is really hard to get from scratch.

Comment: Your questions are too broad to be able to answer specifically and definitively.  If you're looking for a conversation to help figure out if Cloud Functions is right for your particular use case (which you didn't really mention here), try posting to firebase-talk.  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/firebase-talk

Comment: A LOT of your questions will be answered by going through the Firebase Getting Started Guides and writing some code. Crafting a very very basic app to upload a photo and write some user data would be a very worthwhile test of the product and give you a much better feel if it will meet your use case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main difference between Firebase and the traditional setup you describe is that with Firebase, as far as the app developer is concerned, the client has direct access to the database, without the need for an intermediate custom API layer. Firebase provides SDKs in various languages that you would typically use to fetch the data you need / commit data updates.

You also have admin SDKs that you can use server-side, but these are meant for you to run some custom business logic - such as analytics, caching in an external service, for exemple - not for you to implement a data fetching API layer.

This has 2 important consequences:

1. You must define security rules to control who is allowed to read/write at what paths in your database. These security rules are defined at the project level, and rely on the authenticated user (using Firebase Authentication). Typically, if you store the user profile at the path `users/$userId`, you would define a rule saying that this node can be written to only if the authenticated user has an id of `$userId`.
2. You must structure your data in a way that makes it easily readable - without the need for complex database operations such as JOINs that are not supported by Firebase (you do have some limited querying options tough).

These 2 points allow you to skip the 2 main roles of traditional APIs: validating access and fetching/formatting the data.

Cloud functions allow you to react to data changes. Let's say everytime a new user is created, you want to send him a Welcome email: you could define a cloud function sending this email everytime a new node is appended to the `users` path. They allow you to run the code you would typically run server-side when writes happen, so they can have a very broad range of use-cases: side-effects (such as sending an email), caching data in an external service, caching data within Firebase for easier reads, analytics, etc..

Comment: I'm humbled by how well your answer was written compared to mine. =)

Answer (score 3):

1. You don't really need a server, you can access the database directly from the client, as long as your users are authenticated and you have defined reasonable security rules on Firebase.
2. In your use case you could, for example, use cloud functions to create a thumbnail when someone uploads a photo (Firebase Cloud Functions has ImageMagick included for that), or to denormalize your data so your application is faster, or to generate logs. So, basically you can use them whenever you need to do some server side processing when something changes on your database or storage. But I find cloud functions hard to develop and debug, and there are alternatives such as creating a Node application that subscribes to real time changes in your data and processes it. The downside is that you need to host it outside Firebase.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is definitely **NOT** complete or professional, but here are the reasons why I choose `Cloud Functions`

**Performance**

You mentioned that you're writing an instagram-like mobile device app, then I assume that people can comment on others' pictures, as well as view those comments. How would you like to download comments from database and display them on users' devices? I mean, there could be hundreds, maybe thousands of comments on 1 post, you'll need to paginate your results. Why not let the server do all the hard work, free up users' devices and wait for the results? This doesn't seem like a lot better, but let's face it, if your app is incredibly successful, you'll have millions of users, millions of comments that you need to deal with, server will do those hard jobs way better than a mobile phone.

**Security**

If your project is small, then it's true that you won't worry about performance, but what about security? If you do everything on client side, you're basically allowing every device to connect to your database, meaning that every device can read from/write into your database. Once a malicious user have found out your database url, all he has to do is to

```
firebase.database().ref(...).remove();
```

With 1 line of code, you'll lose all your data. Okay, if you say, then I'll just come up with some good security rules like the one below:

[image]

This means that for each post, only the owner of that post can make any changes to it or read from it, other people are forbidden to do anything. It's good, but not realistic. People are supposed to be able to comment on the post, that's modifying the post, this rule will not apply to the situation. But again, if you let everybody read/write, it's not safe again. Then, why not just make `.read` and `.write` false, like this:

[image]

It's 100% safe, because nobody can do anything about anything in your database. Then, you write an API to do all the operations to your database. API limits the operations that can be done to your database. And you have experience in writing APIs, I'm sure you can do something to make your API strong in terms of security, for example, if a user wants to delete a post that he created, in your `deletePost` API, you're supposed to authenticate the user first. This way, 'nobody' can cause any damage to your database.

Comment: I really like your answer. Thank you. But it feels like the Firebase team says: "Hey guys, here is the cool & easy thing" and we are like "Nope, let's do things traditionally". Don't we lose the benefits of Firebase when doing so? Is it ok?

Comment: True, unless you can come up with some good security rules, but that always has loopholes in it. Another thing I like about firebase is that, you won't have to refresh to get the most recent result. In my project, I only allow users to directly read from `users` table, which stores their info. If they change their user name, or profile picture url, they won't have to refresh the app to see the change, instead, all info is updated automatically, which saves a lot of work for me too. My security rule for `users` table is: `"users": {"$uid": {".read": "$uid === auth.uid", ".write": false}}`

Comment: So, is right in his answer and I should not implement API layer?

Comment: @NikitaMarinosyan if what you’re trying to accomplish is not a heavy work, and at the same time, would not give anybody too many privileges, then you won’t have to write an API for it. In my case, I’m letting a user read his own info, which is not heavy & all he can do is to read his own info, as the security rules defined, then it’s fine, I don’t see why not

Comment: thank you, mate! I wish I could mark your answer as solution :C

Comment: @NikitaMarinosyan who’s stopping you lol, just kidding. Or an upvote will do!